# If a line of code in an Excel macro is to long will it cause an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Macro that clears certain cells in column F in my sheet. Here is the code that I am using.

```
 Sub ClearCells()
 Range("F1,F2,F5,F6,F9,F10,F13,F14,F17,F18,F21,F22,F25,F26,F29,F30,F33,F34,F37,F38,F41,F42,F45,F46,F49,F50,F53,F54,F57,F58,F61,F62,F65,F66,F69,F70,F73,F74,F77,F78,F81,F82,F85,F86,F89,F90,F93,F94,F97,F98,F101,F102,F105,F106,F109,F110,F113,F114,F117,F118,F121,F122,F125,F126,F129,F130,F133,F134,F137,F138,F141,F142").ClearContents
 End Sub
```

When I run it, I get this error.
"Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_global' failed"

It worked fine before I added F49-F142. The cells that I am trying to clear are not locked either so I'm not sure what else would be causing that error.

Comment: create an array of strings of the range addresses, that are less than 255 characters.  Loop that array and clear them

Comment: A physical line of VBA code cannot legally exceed 1023 characters, and IIRC a logical line of code cannot exceed 20 physical lines. The error you're getting has nothing to do with that though.

Comment: Technically what you have here is a range `Union`; you could have that long string of cells in a string, split it into an array, then iterate that array to `Union` the ranges, and invoke `ClearContents` on the union'd range.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop:

```
Sub ClearCells()

Dim i as long

For i = 1 to 141 step 4
    Range("F" & i & ":F" & i + 1).clearcontents
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd probably go with a `Union` range and keep it a single `.ClearContents` call though.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you don't want to clear the lock cells in the range you describe, try the following:

```
For i = 1 To 141
    If Not Cells(i, 6).Locked = True Then
        Cells(i, 6).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
```

Please note: you could write `If Not Cells(i, 6).Locked Then` instead of `If Not Cells(i, 6).Locked = True Then`.

Comment: Nice catch! Consider using `Union` to keep it a single `ClearContents` call though - interacting with individual cells will negatively impact performance.